# Is write() or printf() better?

Tags: c, optimization

printf is better because ...

- It buffers the output
- It does string formatting

write is better because ...

- It does not have to calculate the string length
- It is much easier to debug because it does not buffer
- printf is just a wrapper for write
- It does not use any memory an output buffer
- Because of the above reasons, it is possible to create a much more optimal (higher speed with smaller memory footprint) program with write than with printf by passing the string lenghts (which are often already known and need not be recalculated) and managing a buffer internally (which only takes the memory actually needed, not some amount that cannot be influenced by the programmer).
- There is probably some overhead in printf() even when it is called only with a non-formatted string

To conclude, I would argue that printf() is to be preferred for all kinds of debug-output for human consumption (because of string-formatting) while write() is to be preferred for outputting data in normal operation.

Any further thoughts?

Comment: This is a rather broad question with a more opinionated answer.

Comment: `write()` does not buffer? On `stdout`? You serious?

Comment: Also, which one is better? `curl_easy_init()` or `archive_create()`?

Comment: The `write(2)` syscall is not buffering, the kernel may have some cache for filesystems (but these "buffers" stay in kernel, not inside the application)

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch The thing is that buffering is tied to a file. And the syscall just respect a file's "bufferedness".

Comment: No, the filesystem cache inside the kernel is tied to fileysystems and the entire file machinery. Each individual file has no specific buffer in the filesystem cache, but may sit there in chunks.

Answer (score 1):

It actually depends upon the operating system. On Linux and many Unixes, [write(2)](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man2/write.2.html) is a low-level [syscall](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man2/syscalls.2.html) so is the fundamental, lowest-level, operation to do some output. (and `printf` is a library function built above `write`).

However, `write(2)` operation do have an overhead, and for performance reasons you want to buffer your output, which `<stdio.h>` standard functions (like `printf`) do very well. In simple words, avoid calling `write(2)` with small amount of data (a good buffer size is often several kilobytes). The `fflush` library function is flushing buffers (so may call `write`).